# Is it possible to create a popup window in Android that displays a live video feed via a texture view?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, dji-sdk

I am currently building out our application to display a live video feed from the DJI SDK mobile on the android application. However, I am having a hard time figuring out how to display the popup with a texture view as the SDK states it needs to display on for the video feed to work. Has anyone created a popup with a texture view within it?

Answer (score -1):

You can try to create custom window with TextureView and read buffer without any problem.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).